# Ajax on woocommerce widget cart

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, widget, cart

I have woocommerce installed on wordpress with Storefront theme. I've inserted the widget "WooCommerce Cart" on the side bar. I need to add and delete product on the widget cart using ajax. I saw some pages and answer on stackoverflow, but nothing worked for me.

Please suggest! Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. It would be helpful to have mockups or pseude code or something to show us what you want. For me it makes no sense "add product, to delete product" are these seperate action? What answers have you looked at? And why don't they answer your question?

Comment: @RolandStuder Another user ask on stackoverflow.com "how to delete a product in the mini-cart width ajax", but no one answer was helpfull for me. My site is [this](https://shop.crushi.it/05-17), and in the right siderbar, once you add a product in the mini-cart, when you go to delete, it refresh all the content of the page. I've try to modify mini-cart.php, cart.php, class-wc-ajax.php, without success. Do you know other possibility solution?